# Parallax. Как прокручивать фон только при прокрутке до определенного блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `DIV` с parallax-эффектом. `DIV` находится не вначале страницы, ближе к концу.

**JS-код parallax-эффекта:**

```
$('#block').each(function(){
    var $bgobj = $(this);
    $window.on('load scroll', function() {
        var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / 10);
        var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';
        $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
    });
});
```

Проблема в том, что фон начинает прокручиваться сразу с началом прокрутки страницы. Как сделать прокрутку фона только после того, как пользователь прокрутил страницу до этого блока?

Comment: Ну наверное узнать на какой высоте от верха страницы находится блок и проверить это значение в функции, если докрутил до этой высоты - выполнять действия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var place = document.getElementById('place');
var placeSourceBottom = place.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > placeSourceBottom) {
    ваше условие
  }
```

где `place` это ваш блок. Код для js